# Mac Kernel Panic - gutenprint.5.2

Tags: macos, kernel, panic

Recently my laptop has been having Kernel Panics once every few days. I can't find a certain program that is making it happen, or a certain task that I perform.

I read that you can look in the .crash reports for a possible cause. So here is part of one I found.

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libgutenprint.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/cups/driver/gutenprint.5.2
  Reason: image not found
```

I am wondering if gutenprint.5.2 could be the reason for the Kernel crashing. If so, should I remove it? Install an update?

Thanks!

Comment: No. User-space library load failures do not cause kernel panics.

Comment: Agreed; what makes you think this is a kernel panic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a kernel panic. You'll find kernel panic reports in Console.app, under system diagnostic reports. They start with "kernel" and end with ".panic". Unless you wrote the driver that's crashing, this is the wrong site to post such questions. Try the Ask Different sister site at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead.